# The integral of $\int\frac{1}{sinhx}$

Tags: calculus

I was given as HW to calaulate the integral:
$\int\frac{1}{sinhx}$. The clue was to to do it with partial integration. I tried it but it gets more complicated. any help?

Thank you

Comment: Use the definition of $\sinh(x)$

Answer (score 5):

Recall that $$\sinh{x} = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$$
Then

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sinh{x}} = \int \frac{2}{e^x - e^{-x}} dx = \int \frac{2 e^x}{e^{2x} - 1} dx$$

Now make a substitution $u = e^x$ and consider the fraction
$$\frac{1}{u^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{(u - 1)(u + 1)}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sinh x}=2\int\frac{dx}{e^x-e^{-x}}=_{t=e^x}2\int\frac{dt}{t^2-1}\\=\ln\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the integrand as $\frac{\sinh x}{\sinh^2 x}$, and then as $\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh^2 x-1}$. Make the substitution $u=\cosh x$. We end up with
$$\int \frac{du}{u^2-1},$$
a standard partial fractions problem.